# Preferences toolbar without BWToolkit

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Since Xcode 4, using BWToolkit isn't really easy. In fact, it's not even possible in IB.

Is there some sample code out there how to create a "preferences-type toolbar" without BWToolkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [`MVPreferencesController`](http://hg.mozilla.org/camino/file/4a8f1e3d754a/src/preferences) as used by Camino. See [here](http://doxygen.db48x.net/mozilla-full/html/dir_d9688c298855dcc112308ab62a442074.html) for Doxygen documentation. It displays `NSPreferencePane`s registered using a plist. It's pretty easy to work with and customize for your purposes. You can also use the Camino project as a source of [sample prefpanes](http://hg.mozilla.org/camino/file/4a8f1e3d754a/src/preferences).

Comment: The only problem is that this code is GPL. Do you know of any alternatives with a more flexible license such as the MIT license? I need the code for a commercial closed-source product.

Comment: It is not GPL. It is licensed under the Mozilla Public License (MPL) 1.1 with an option to use it in accordance with the GPL or LGPL instead. If all you do is use the MPL code without modifying it, it's just like Apache- or BSD-licensed code, where you just need to give notice that you used the software provided by so-and-so under such-and-such a license. See [Mozilla's FAQ on the MPL](http://www.mozilla.org/MPL/mpl-faq.html). You can read more about the MPL, including an annotated license, [here](http://www.mozilla.org/MPL/).

Comment: Also, if BWToolkit's license is acceptable, why not just use it without using the IB plugins? If all else fails, you can just use a "Custom View" in IB and set the class to the BWToolkit class, then set any BWToolkit-specific properties during your view/window controller's `-awakeFromNib` method.

Comment: You raise some great points and you are of course right. Thank you sir.